# Game Maker Language's random function always giving the same result

Tags: game-maker, random

I'd like to create a Snake game, and for that, I'd like to position the sweet which makes the snake bigger in a random position.

For that, I use this code in the create event of the object bonbon :

```
position_x = round(random(10));
position_y = round(random(10));

x = position_x*16;
y = position_y*16;
```

But the sprite of this object is always in the same position of the room.

I tried changing the argument to the function `random()`, and then it changed the position of the sweet once, but after a rerun, the position doesn't change from that new location.

I think the position of the sweet is set using the argument to the `random()` function.

How can the position of the sweet be randomized? 
Why does the random function return the same values every time I run the game?

Thanks to DMGregory, I changed the code and this code works :

```
randomize();
position_x = irandom(10);
position_y = irandom(10);

x = position_x*16;
y = position_y*16;
```

Comment: You might find [answers to previous GameMaker questions on randomizing](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/139382/39518) useful here.

Comment: Don't edit your answer to the question body. Instead, post it as an answer at the bottom of the site.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the 'random()' function by the 'irandom()', and add the 'randomize()' function, in order to reset the value which are going to be randomized.

```
randomize();
position_x = irandom(10);
position_y = irandom(10);

x = position_x*16;
y = position_y*16;
```

Sorry for the spelling's mistakes, I'm French.

Comment: Note: you souldn't to do `randomize()` each time before get a random value. You should do it only once, when game starts. If you do `randomize()` multiple times, the result will be worst.

Comment: I use `randomize()` only in the `create` event because if I don't do this, the value will not be randomizing.

Comment: If there is only one instance of the object (and created only once) then `Create` event is ok. Otherwise it's not good (for example, then you can place `randomize` at first room's creation code).

Comment: There is only one object with the randomize function. After that, I will change the position of the object with the `collision` event.